# Simplifying comma separated CSS selectors with common prefix/suffix

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to simplify comma separated CSS selectors with common prefix/suffix?

My current style looks like this (much longer though):

```
html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='abc.com'], html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='def.com'], html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='ghi.com'], html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='jkl.com'] {
    display: none!important;
}
```

I'm wondering if something like the following would be possible:

```
html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*=('abc.com', 'def.com', 'ghi.com', 'jkl.com')] {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Cases like these can be somewhat simplified with CSS preprocessors like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: No this is not possible in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments, this is simply not possible with plain CSS right now. Your only option to shorten the selector is to use a pre-processor, like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) (Syntactically Awesome StyleSheets). SASS allows you to write more readable, shorter code. You can compile a SASS (`*.scss`) file to plain CSS on your own computer, so by the time it's on the server, it's the plain old CSS you are used to, understood by all browsers. No extra requirement from your users.

For this particular case, you could use a [for-each loop](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive).

```
@each $domain in 'abc.com', 'def.com', 'ghi.com', 'jkl.com' {
  html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='#{$domain}'] {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

This would result in the following CSS:

```
html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='abc.com'] {
  display: none !important;
}

html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='def.com'] {
  display: none !important;
}

html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='ghi.com'] {
  display: none !important;
}

html:lang(qw) div[data-domain*='jkl.com'] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for my specific case, but I'm accepting the answer since it addresses the general question. Thanks.